# Estrutura de repetição while para calcular novamente em C

Tags: c, c++, do-while

Eu resolvi esse exercício abaixo e pensei em colocar uma estrutura `while` de repetição, para a pessoa calcular novamente. Mas quando eu coloco 's' para retornar e calcular novamente, o exercício soma os valores dos 10 números que calculei anteriormente e soma com os próximos 10 números. Por que isso ocorre?

```
/*Ex: Faça um programa que solicite ao usuário a entrada de 10 números e
imprima como resultado a soma de todos os pares */

int vetor[10], i;
float res=0;
char op;

do {

 for (i=0; i<=9; i++) {

    printf("\nInforme um numero: ");
    scanf("%i", &vetor[i]);

    if (vetor[i] % 2 == 0) {

        res = res + vetor[i];

    }

}

printf("\nA soma dos pares e: %.2f", res);

printf("\nDeseja calcular novamente? ");
scanf("%s", &op);
fflush(stdin);

} while (op == 's' || op == 'S');

return(0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que não está reiniciando o valor da variável `res` quando vai calcular novamente:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int vetor[10], i;
    char op;
    do {
        float res = 0; //agora toda vez que for repetir o pedido vai zerar a variável
        for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            printf("\nInforme um numero: ");
            scanf("%i", &vetor[i]);
            if (vetor[i] % 2 == 0) {
                res += vetor[i];
            }
        }
        printf("\nA soma dos pares e: %.2f", res);
        printf("\nDeseja calcular novamente? ");
        scanf("%s", &op);
        fflush(stdin);
    } while (op == 's' || op == 'S');
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/Ku2B2a). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/komnqvtj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/RepeatWhile.cpp).

Alguns pequenos problemas no código além deste mas que não impede o funcionamento.

Comment: Entendi, era isso mesmo! ;) Obrigada.

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que a variável `res` não tem seu valor reiniciado na próxima iteração do loop `do..while`. Isso pode ser corrigido de duas formas

1- Movendo a declaração da variável `res` para dentro do loop `do...while`:

```
do {

    float res = 0;

    for (i=0; i<=9; i++) {
```

Observe que desta forma o correto é remover a declaração prévia da variável `res`, já que ela não será utilizada devido às diferenças de escopos.

2- Reiniciando seu valor a cada iteração do `do...while` através de uma atribuição apenas:

```
do {

    res = 0;

    for (i=0; i<=9; i++) {
```

*Observação*

Como `res` recebe apenas valores inteiros, ela não precisa ser declarada como `float`, sendo suficiente declara-la como `int` ou como `long`, caso acredite que seus valores irão causar `integer overflow`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigada gente, me ajudaram muito! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode usar o `while` da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 10

int main(void)
{
    int vetInt[MAX], soma_par, i, op;           

    while(1)
    {
        soma_par = 0;
        printf("\nInforme 10 numeros inteiros.\n");

        /*Leitura dos numeros inteiros.*/
        for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        {
            printf("\nInforme o %i° numero: ", i + 1);
            scanf("%i", &vetInt[i]);
        }

        /*Soma dos numeros pares.*/
        for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
            if (vetInt[i] % 2 == 0)
                soma_par += vetInt[i];

        printf("\nSoma de todos numeros pares é %i\n\n", soma_par);

        printf("\nDigite 0 para finalizar o programa ou 1 para continuar: ");
        scanf("%d", &op);

        if (op == 0)
            break;
        else
            system("clear");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Neste caso para encerrar o *loop* e necessário que o usuário digite **0**, assim o *loop* sera encerrado pelo `break;`.

Comment: Obrigada Dener, vou tentar resolver desse jeito também. ;)